# Merge Multiple text files into one text file (and back to original files) lua and php

Tags: php, file, text, lua

Basically i have a lua client, and a php server. Lets say i have a directory on the server with multiple text files, for example:

- Directory on server

  - file1
  - file2
  - file3

I would like to take all of the files in a directory and consolidate them into one, however i want it to be able to take the file and put the files back with the names. Meaning in the condensed file there would have to be a header for each segment (text from a file) For example

Condensed Text File:

```
header for file1 to identify it for later use
file1's contents here
header for file2 to identify it for later use
file2's contents here
header for file3 to identify it for later use
file3's contents here
```

this way it can be put back into place with the contents and names.

PHP: I need php to condense a folders contents into one text file (all folder items are text files) so i can send it to the lua client

LUA: I need lua to be able to take that data from the php server and uncondense the files into a specified folder

I Do not want to use actual compression algorithms i just want to make all the text files into one and then put them back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating files with the markers in PHP should be straightforward, something like

```
$fpAll = fopen("fileAll", w+);
$file1 = file_get_contents("file1");
$file2 = file_get_contents("file2");
$h = "# some file separation marker line";
$all = $h + "\n" + $file1 + $h + "\n" + $file2 ...;
... send $all to client ...
```

On the Lua side, assuming an HTTP lib that provides response as a file-like object,

```
separatonMarker = "# some file separation marker line"
files = {}
fileCount = 0
for line in response:lines() do
     if line == separationMarker then
         nextFile = {}
         fileCount = fileCount + 1
         files[fileCount] = nextFile
     else
         table.insert(nextFile, line) -- append to end
     end
end
```

If you want to save files locally you would open a file just before creating the new nextFile and save each line from nextFile into it.